# Mystery Memory Leak when overwriting a static DataSet

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I am running a test function to identify a memory leak:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DatabaseTools_Other_MemoryTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var r = DatabaseTools.GetDataSet(true);
            r = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            int EndPoint = i;
        }
    }        
}
```

The goal of this method is to call DatabaseTools.GetDataSet(true) until it hits an OutOfMemoryException, which happens during the 3rd or 4th load. However, as I understand it, this shouldn't actually ever happen- this is DatabaseTools.GetDataSet:

```
public static DataSet GetDataSet(bool setData, string sqlText = null, string strConnection = null)
{
    sqlText = sqlText ?? FullFilemakerQuery;

    if (setData)
    {
        Database = strConnection;
        Data = new DataSet();
    }

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnectionString())
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlText, connection))
        {
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            if (setData)
            {
                dataAdapter.FillSchema(Data, SchemaType.Source);
                DisableAutoIncrement(Data);
                dataAdapter.Fill(Data);
                NameTables(Data, sqlText);

                BuildDataKeysAndRelations(Database);
                dataSet = null;
            }
            else
            {
                dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source);
                DisableAutoIncrement(dataSet);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
                NameTables(dataSet, sqlText);
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    return dataSet ?? Data;
}

public static void NameTables(DataSet dataSet, string sqlText)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables.Count; i++)
    {
        dataSet.Tables[i].TableName = sqlText.Split(';')[i].Split(Dividers, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim();
    }
}

public static void DisableAutoIncrement(DataSet data)
{
    foreach (DataTable T in data.Tables)
    {
        T.PrimaryKey.Select(c => { c.AutoIncrement = false; return c; }).ToList();
    }
}
```

When passing only 'true' to this function, it sets sqlText equal to a static FullFileMakerQuery which selects everything the program could use from the database, it then gets the default database name (Database has a custom setter such that when given a null or empty value, it sets itself to default), and sets the static Data to a new DataSet. We have tried setting it to null at this point (no change) and we have tried using Data.Dispose() which caused errors. Because this function can also just return the dataset without also setting the global Data to it, we initialize a new DataSet dataSet. Then we do the standard connect, data adapter, fillschema, load data.

The weirdness: by setting breakpoints in the memory test function and saving dumps, loading the dataset once takes some amount of memory, reloading it uses *less* memory (by about 36,000 bytes in System.Data.Common.StringStorage) and then reloading it again uses *more* memory (by about 120,000 bytes in the same place as before). If we reload it one more time, it uses even more memory and crashes due to an OutOfMemoryException, and at this point I have no idea what could be causing it.

Comment: I'm suspecting the `BuildDataKeysAndRelations` method. Could you show the content of that method?

Comment: You have mixed to things here: getting data and holding data. You would have a much cleaner program (and easier way to see the mistakes) if you'd separate those two concerns.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo I did too, but commenting out that line had no effect on the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You never call `.Dispose()` on your `DataSet`, neither on the return value, nor on your static variable before you call `new` again.

As you are using `using` blocks with other classes already, I guess you know what to do to actually call `.Dispose()` on it.

Turn on Visual Studio Static Code Analysis, it will give you warnings should you forget to do so.

Comment: We've actually tried that- changing the code to

    if (setData)
    {
        if (Data != null)
        {
             Data.Dispose();
         }
         Database = strConnection;
         Data = new DataSet();
    }

And adding a dispose statement before dataSet = null; has no effect.